# set focus to textbox from angularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am creating a web app in which I am using angularJS, I have a jqueryui datepicker , which looks like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="rc.reg.mddoj" ng-blur="rc.dojChange()" title="Date Of Joining" placeholder="Date Of Joining" class="form-control" datepicker />
```

and in my controller

```
r.dojChange = function () {
    var currentTarget = event.target;
    setTimeout(function () { r.reg.mddoj = currentTarget.value; }, 500);
}
```

and after executing this I want to set focus to my next control

```
<input type="text" ng-model="rc.reg.mdemail" title="EmailID" placeholder="EmailID" class="form-control validatingData" />
```

how can I set control to elements from angularJS controller.

I just want to set focus to my element from a directive and want to call the directive in my `r.dojChange function()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To focus an element from your AngularJS code you have to execute the following:

```
$timeout(function() {
   const elementToFocus = $element[0].querySelector(<SELECTOR TO YOUR ELEMENT>);
   if (elementToFocus) {
      elementToFocus.focus();
   }
}, 0);
```

Comment: actually i had done like this before,

i had seen some example in which they used directive, but i was not able to achieve that but want to do like that

Comment: As I understand you want to set focus on the next element after a date from the date picker is selected? Are you sure you need directive then? Since it will not be clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `setTimeout` you must use `$scope.$apply()` to ensure changes to the scope is taken care of. Or you could use `$timeout` :

```
r.dojChange = function() {
  var currentTarget = event.target;
  $timeout(function() {
    r.reg.mddoj = currentTarget.value; 
    document.querySelector('[title="EmailID"]').focus(); //<---
  }, 500)
}
```